# The electric field should be in circular coil. But why do current flows in whole circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

We know changing magnetic flux induces electric field which makes current to flow .here in the below picture the flux is changing through only circular coil bout not through the rectangular part.so what induces electric field in rectangular part for current to complete the circuit ..Note that the electric field is required inside awire to make the current flow.[image: https://photos.app.goo.gl/RmoxRV8KgUN7BrU27]

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/540286/2451

Comment: Hi Mogilipu Sharada. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Answer (score 0):

When you move the magnet through the loop, you induce a collective shift of electrons in the metal wire. At one end of the loop there is an excess of electrons and at the other end there is a shortage of electrons. This potential difference is equalized over the whole wire, you get a current.

Answer (score 0):

By moving a magnet, voltage will be induced in the circular part of the coil (which is in the range of magnetic field). This voltage will drive the current in rest of the part of wire.

Answer (score 0):

The field induced in the circular part of the circuit causes the free carriers (electrons) in the wire of that part of the circuit to move slightly. The the movement of the electrons from one end of the loop to the other creates the field in the other part of the circuit.