# What induces electric field that drives current through whole circuit

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

We know changing magnetic flux induces electric field which makes current to flow .here in the below picture the flux is changing through only circular coil bout not through the rectangular part.so what induces electric field in rectangular part for current to complete the circuit ..Note that the electric field is required inside awire to make the current.[image: https://photos.app.goo.gl/qksyGmtLV2PH61Tm9[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfBAc.png)